Can an orphan be bar mitzvah before he is 13?
In the biography of Rabbi Aryeh Levin, zt'l, "A Tzaddik in Our Time," Raz, Simcha (Feldheim 1976), p. 76, I found a surprising statement:  "When a certain orphan boy became bar-mitzvah (on his twelfth birthday rather than his thirteenth, because he was an orphan), Reb Aryeh went to the family's celebration of the happy event...."
I never heard of such a thing.  What source brings this halacha (or minhag) down?

The appendix to https://www.chaimsimons.net/tephillinage12.pdf has some info. I can't speak to its reliability, and it doesn't exactly answer the question, which is why I'm posting it as a comment rather than as an answer.
